# Custom Wordpress plugins on 2nd server are breaking permalinks

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, permalinks

I have a wordpress site that sits on one server and a copy of the site on a second server, both connect to the same database. The purpose of the copy on the second server is to run several custom plugins I have written, they're quite resource intensive when they run so the site would grind to a halt if they were on the first server.

The problem is, every time they run they break the frontend sites permalinks, saving the permalinks page in admin fixes them until the plugins run again.

I know it's not the code in the plugins as I've tested calling an empty plugin with no code at all in it, if it runs on the second server it breaks the permalinks. Also, checked running on the plugins on first server and that does not break the permalinks.

The .htaccess files on both servers are identical, also tried deleting the one on the second server but that that didn't work either.

Any help to fix this or even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I love problems like this and would love to solve it for you fully, but I am going to go for pointing you in the right direction, because I don't have the time to set it up and also do the testing involved in getting this working.

Of course, as you probably know (but for the sake of others), you can easily use the same Database between to Wordpress installs as long as you have different table prefixs.  The trick would being able to share all or some of the tables between both installs without problems like you are experiencing. I don't know which tables you need to be available to your plugins, but if you could just make the ones you need available without making them all, then in theory you should be able to avoid the problem.

I am betting that the problem here is with the `options` table. I think the key to solving would be studying how Wordpress already has created a solution to share the `users` and `usermeta` tables between installs.

This is done by defining them in the wp-settings.php file using `define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');` and `define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');`

You can see how that is accomplished in the `install directory/wp-includes/wp-db.php` file. On the current Wordpress version see line 887, and then especially the lines of code starting on 953...

```
if ( isset( $tables['users'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) )
                $tables['users'] = CUSTOM_USER_TABLE;
```

I would think you could simply modify this code to share the tables you need from the "front-end" install with your second install, and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer. I found a work around by calling `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );` from the first server after each plugin has run. But your idea seems a bit more elegant so I will have a look at that.